# In the context of Quantum theory of Information, Typical eigenvectors are permutations of basis vectors. Why?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises

[image: Heading]

Why is this so? Can someone please give me detailed steps with an explanation?

Comment: Welcome on the QC SE! Please don't use screenshots, they are not searchable. Use Latex and text copy-paste.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, this is not a general property but it happens to be because we typically choose, in the qubit case for example, operators that anti-commute.

Let $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ be two such operators that satisfy $\sigma_i^2=I$ and
$$
\sigma_1\sigma_2+\sigma_2\sigma_1=0.
$$
Since they square to identity, the eigenvalues must be $\pm 1$. Now let $|\psi_{\pm}\rangle$ be the corresponding eigenvectors of $\sigma_1$ with eigenvalues $\pm1$. We see that
$$
(\sigma_1\sigma_2+\sigma_2\sigma_1)|\psi_{\pm}\rangle=0=(\sigma_1\mp I)\sigma_2|\psi_{\pm}\rangle.
$$
So, $\sigma_2|\psi_{\pm}\rangle$ are the 0 vectors of $\sigma_1\pm I$ respectively, and are hence eigenvectors of $\sigma_1$ with eigenvalues $\mp1$. Thus, $\sigma_2|\psi_{\pm}\rangle=|\psi_{\mp}\rangle$, which is a permutation.

It might help to visualise what's going on on the Bloch sphere. Pick an axis. Let's say the $z$ axis for the sake of argument. We do a rotation such that two rotations returns everything to the same point it started, i.e. we do a rotation half way around the Bloch sphere. So, any point on the equator is mapped to its antipodal point, corresponding to an orthogonal state. Thus, this $z$ rotation acts as a permutation for any orthogonal basis on the equator, such as the $x$ or $y$ axes.

This choice is particularly convenient in quantum information because it means that the bases *mutually unbiased*, which has useful properties in, for example, cryptography applications.